# How to re-generate the user.confirmation_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm looking for a way to regenerate the user.confirmation_token. In my app, I allow users to deactivate their account with user.deleted_at. If a deactivate user tries to re-activate their account, I want to see a confirmation_instructions mail but need a confirmation token set. Is there a way with devise to re-generate the user.confirmation_token inside the RegistrationsController?

Answer (score 0):

Theres the `generate_confirmation_token` method in the `Confirmable` module which is applied to other classes via `ActiveSupport::Concern`. Like you see here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

Reapllying this method on your User object should do the Trick.

// The `generate_confirmation_token` method is protected so it cant be called from outside the class. You can run `send_confirmation_instructions` which generates the token and delivers a registration mail.

// Watching at the source if the `confirmable` module of the gem let it look like the method does. If it isnt possible by default you need to costumize the gem. You can get the gemsets path by the following command in the bash

```
rvm gemset path
```

then in the `gems` directory you will find the version of devise installed. In the `lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb` file you can add a not protected method that calls the `generate_confirmation_token` method. You can only call it from that module because its protected.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working. How would I apply/user it in the registrations_controller? Thanks

Comment: what happens if you simply run `user.generate_confirmation_token`?

Comment: That is errors with: NoMethodError (protected method `generate_confirmation_token!' called for #<User:0x007fc9b5c880a8>):

Comment: send_confirmation_instructions, does not generate a confirmation token.